# What time is it telling? Grandpa's weird clock

Tags: riddle

I saw this on Grandpa's desk today.

"Is this some kind of clock?", I asked him

His usual non-answer reply

"May be. At my age this is all I need- timewise-son"

What is it? How can we explain the time--if that is what it is.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This 'clock' is actually:

> A **CALENDAR**!

Here each number on a normal clock face:

> has been replaced by the A1Z26 numeric value representing the initial letter of that numbered month (i.e. 1 becomes 10 - 'J' for January, etc.)

The arrow shows Grandpa:

> The current month - 15 is 'O' for October! (The year in sequence is J-F-M-A-M-J-J-A-S-O-N-D - or 10-6-13-1-13-10-10-1-19-15-14-4 as depicted here...)

Comment: Could you not wait until I finish writing the question???? Amazing

Comment: Ha! Sorry @DrD :) I was testing out my time machine ;-)

Comment: Jeez that was fast, by the time I saw this puzzle it was solved, by the way I created a puzzle with you in mind today, want to have a stab? I think you are probably the only person that can solve it here.

Comment: @Deepthinker101 Aha, I think I know it - just need some time! Don't rule out the rest of the community so quickly though - I wouldn't be surprised if someone else gets it in the meantime! :)